# How do I put this into code?

Tags: logic, sense

I'm struggling on how I can put this into code.

int a=500;

By default x = a-100
I am trying to find a way where when **one** button is clicked, it sets the x-coordinate to x=a-100 , and then when the same button is pressed again, it sets x=0.

How would i logically put this into code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use a flag (Boolean variable) or a counter to keep track of how many times the button has been pressed.

Comment: Could you show me an example please?

At the moment, I am using a returning a boolean when the button is pressed and setting the values, but not sure how to reverse the changes in a way.

Comment: I'm on my phone. I'll see if I can whip some pseudocode up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere, have a variable keep track of whether or not the button has been previously pressed. Since you haven't indicated what language you're using, I'll have to make this very generic, and assume the typical interface that's used to handle button press events.

```
var button = (some GUI button object);

var a = 500;
var x = 2;

var buttonHasBeenPressed = false;

button.onPress = function() {
    if (buttonHasBeenPressed) {
        x = 0;

    } else {
        x = a - 100;
    }

    buttonHasBeenPressed = true;
};
```

Where you store the flag (`buttonHasBeenPressed`) depends on your skill level, the size of your program and many other factors. This is just a rough example using pseudo-javascript.

Comment: @user3196556 Np. Keep in mind, if you need to do this for many different buttons, you'll want to encapsulate this is a class. Pasting  this code everywhere would be a bad idea.

Comment: @user3196556 Please up vote this too if it helped you :).